# Is it okay to use Capital letters for H F D in "Happy Friendship Day"

Tags: grammar

While writing Happy Friendship Day is it okay to use H F and D as capital letters ?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely okay.

This is called "title case", and is the capitalization used in (for example) book and film titles. The first word and other important words are capitalized, minor words (the, in, of ...) are not. So we get *"Close Encounters of the Third Kind"*

Utterances that are not intended as full sentences are sometimes written in title case. So we say "Happy Birthday!" or "Good Luck!" or "Happy Friendship Day!". But if the words are part of a sentence, capitalize normally; "She had had good luck at the casino." "He hoped that she would have a happy birthday."

However, it doesn't matter much. Getting the capitalization wrong doesn't affect understanding or meaning.